# separate a number from a word

Tags: php, regex, string, replace

Basically I have this string :

```
"We spent 10minutes talking while traveling 20kms"
```

How can I transform it to :

```
"We spent 10 minutes talking while traveling 20 kms"
```

Basically seperating every digit or number attached to word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
$str = preg_replace('/(\d)([a-z])/i', '$1 $2', $str);
```

`\d` matches a digit, `[a-z]` matches a letter.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it works also perfectly, I find the first one more elegant though.

Comment: This might have a problem if the OP is accepting user input and can't guarantee a *word* is `[a-z]`.

Comment: - This regex only matches a single digit followed by a letter. While it does work for this example, it's rather limited.

Comment: @JasonMcCreary It only needs to match the last digit of the number and the first character of the word.

Comment: @jason McCreary Did lot of tests, from them the one mentioned on the comment on the first answer, and this didn't fail so far, I tried with several digits with different lengths, also with given _ or - or blank after the digits it doesnt separate anything which is wanted.

Comment: @FaouziNikolaic If you use this, it may be better to swap `[a-z]` with `\pL`, which will match a *letter* as defined by Unicode.

Comment: @alex Thanks a lot for the tip, tried it working flawlessly, that just made this regex perfect,thanks for the great contribution spirit !

Answer (score 3):

You could use everybody's friend, the regex!

```
$str = preg_replace("/\d+\B/", "$0 ", $str);
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.org/WmP6rNJR).

This will match a series of decimal numbers that have a non-word boundary immediately following them.

Alternatively, you could do this...

```
$str = preg_replace("/(\d)(\D)/", "$1 $2", $str);
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.org/VgLEDZhY).

This will match a decimal number that is immediately followed by a non decimal number.

Comment: Thanks that's an elegant solution, working perfectly ! Alternative too, love it :)

Comment: The second version will turn something like `10-20` to `10 -20`. Is that desired?

Comment: No actually I only want the whitespace if there is just letters after it. It seems like the alternative will fail on that, thanks for catching it !

Comment: The first version and my answer are equivalent except for one case: a number followed by underscore. Mine won't match, alex's will.

Comment: Actually while doing some tests I found that the first version fails on this case : A car spent 200 s to travel 1000m.
It returns A car spent 20 0 s to travel 1000m. While for the second version it works perfectly

Comment: That's because when it gets to `200<space>`, it backs up one character so that the boundary between the last two `0`s will match `\B`.

Comment: Yeah that what seems to happen, so far the second answer been working better